# How to verify attributes containing in list

Tags: java, cucumber

I having API response like this:

```
"Name": [
  {
    "abc": "xyz",
    "abc1": "xyz2"              
  },
  {
    "abc": "yzk",
    "abc1": "xyz21"
  },
  {
    "abc": "zxc",
    "abc1": "xyz211"
  }
]
```

I want to verify that NAME attributes contains all mentioned key value pair using java

Can someone explain?

Comment: Do show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Cucumber question. It is rather a question about how you can transform some `json` to something you can verify is correct.

I can see three or four different apporaches, they all involve an external library for parsing the `json` and transforming it into a Java object that you can assert using your regular assertion framework.

Start by asking your devs what library they use for dealing with `json`. If your project doesn't have a preferred way to deal with `json`, I would add a test dependency to

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.json</groupId>
  <artifactId>json</artifactId>
  <version>20180813</version>
</dependency>
```

and use it to parse the `json`string to an object that can be verified.

It may be worth noting that your example isn't valid `json` as it doesn't start with an `{` or ends with an `}`

Fixing this gives a sample that looks like this:

```
{"Name": [
  {
    "abc1": "xyz2",
    "abc": "xyz"
  },
  {
    "abc1": "xyz21",
    "abc": "yzk"
  },
  {
    "abc1": "xyz211",
    "abc": "zxc"
  }
]}
```

With this sample, I was able to implement an example that looks like this:

```
package se.thinkcode;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

public class ParseJson {

    @Test
    public void verifyNameArray() {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(getSample());
        JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Name");

        assertThat(array.length()).isEqualTo(3);
    }

    private String getSample() {
        return "{\n" +
                "\"Name\": [\n" +
                "  {\n" +
                "    \"abc\": \"xyz\",\n" +
                "    \"abc1\": \"xyz2\"              \n" +
                "  },\n" +
                "  {\n" +
                "    \"abc\": \"yzk\",\n" +
                "    \"abc1\": \"xyz21\"\n" +
                "  },\n" +
                "  {\n" +
                "    \"abc\": \"zxc\",\n" +
                "    \"abc1\": \"xyz211\"\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                "]" +
                "\n}";
    }
}
```

Your task is to take the array, inspect each element in it and see if it contains what you need.